# SourceTree not showing remote repositories

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

In Source Tree 2.3.1 I click Remote on the toolbar to see the remote repositories but none show.

Nothing happens when I click Refresh

Answer (score 1):

I clicked Edit Accounts, then Add.
I selected OAuth for authentication and clicked Refresh OAuth Token. After this the remote repositories became visible.

The problem re-appeared the next day.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved when I did this: I closed the SourceTree Windows app and opened it again. I was able to see the remote repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Git clone your repository, and open it locally with sourceTree